# How can I read a varying amount of integer input in C?

Tags: c, input

I will be getting three lines of input. The first line will give me 2 integers and the third line will give me 1 integer. But the second line can give me any number of integers ranging between 1 to 100. For example, the input could be:

```
2 1
5 6 1 9 2
10
```

or could be:

```
10 4
5 6
9
```

I can read the second line of integer input into an integer array for a fixed number of integers, but cannot do so for a varying number of integers. I suppose, in this case, I should use a while loop which will break when `scanf()` finds a newline. How do I code that?

Comment: `How do I code that?`.....DV magnet. Brace yourself.

Comment: somewhat related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089140/c-how-to-read-inputs?rq=1

Comment: If there is a reasonably small upper bound on the number of ints on a line you could just declare an array big enough to accommodate them all. `int numbers[100];` uses a negligible amount of memory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125445/multiple-inputs-by-user-dynamically-at-runtime#comment48361721_30125445

Comment: @CoolGuy the link you provided solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read the line into a buffer ([@John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568828/how-can-i-read-a-varying-amount-of-integer-input-in-c#comment54915660_33568828)) using using `fgets()`   or `getline()`.
2. Parse the string looking for whitespace that may contain a `'\n'`, exit loop if found.  Then call `strtol()` or `sscanf()` to read the 1 number.  Check that function's return value for errors too.
3. Repeat above steps.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually a newbie in programming and am unaware of most of the functions. The only string functions I know of are `strlen()` and `strcmp()`. And my i\o function knowledge is limited to `printf()` and `scanf()`.

Anyhow, I solved my problem in this way:

```
int a[101];
int i, num;
char ch;

for (i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    a[i] = 0;

while (1)
{
    scanf("%d%c", &num, &ch);
    i = num;
    a[i] = num;
    if (ch == '\n')
        break;
}
```

This works! 
The value of `num` had to be equal to the value `i` because my program needed it.

Comment: Notes: 1) `for (i = 0; i < 101; i++) a[i] = 0;` writes outside `a[]` which is _undefined behavior_ 2) `scanf("%d%c", &num, &ch);` does not check the result of `scanf()`, so code does not know the values of `num`, `ch` are valid.

Comment: @chux Thank you for pointing those things out. I fixed the first thing you mentioned. Next, I didn't check if `num` and `ch` are valid or not because it was competitive programming problem and we were only given integer inputs. However, your insight will be useful in real life problems. I appreciate that.

Comment: @chux I fixed it according to your suggestion.